# Virtual machine with VirtualBox find and execute local C file

Tags: c, linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am learning C at the moment and my university requires me to use a Virtual Maschine running Linux using VirtualBox. If I write a c program in my compiler (Codeblocks) on my Windows operating system, I do not know how I could execute the written C file.

At this website: https://www.howtogeek.com/189974/how-to-share-your-computers-files-with-a-virtual-machine/ I have seen that this can be done by "Insert Guest Additions CD image" and then adjusting "shared folders" in the settings.

Would this be the right approach? Can you give some examples of how I would then execute the code in the VM?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you write the code on your native Windows OS and you want to compile and run it on a Linux VM. Is that right? Is there a reason you are not editing the code directly on the VM with vim, emacs, or some other text editor? I understand these can be intimidating to learn, but the time spent doing so is highly worth it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to compile it inside linux using clang or gcc because the windows version of codeblocks will compile it for windows, then the simplest solution is just cooy/paste the source code on linux or doing shared folders it is simple you go to the virtual box setting and install virtualbox guest additions and also install it inside the virtual machine, but what i would do is just do the whole thing in linux :)

Answer (score 0):

The link you give shows how to share files between your native OS and the virtual machine. This is a perfectly acceptable way to transfer a file which is already in Windows. However, it would be much simpler to create the file in the VM in the first place. I suggest you learn how to use vim or emacs to edit your code files in Linux.